# Eclipse java JAX-RPC web service import generates an interface instead of a class

Tags: java, web-services

therefore, when trying to instantiate an object of the class, the error is

`Cannot instantiate the type`

[image]

Does anyone know why Eclipse would generate an interface instead of a class? The web service was originally written in VB.Net but can be replicated following the simple example given [here](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/08/web-services-an-introduction/)

1. Start an eclipse project.
2. Add a new Web Service client http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL
3. Write the code...

   ```
   package test;

   import NET.webserviceX.www.CurrencyConvertor; 
   import NET.webserviceX.www.CurrencyConvertorSoap; 
   import NET.webserviceX.www.Currency;

   public class Convert 
   {
       public static void main(String[] args) 
       {
           CurrencyConvertor cc = new CurrencyConvertor();
           // Gets an implementation of the interface we can use
           // to contact the web service.
           CurrencyConvertorSoap ccs = cc.getCurrencyConvertorSoap();

           // Send the SOAP request to the server and get the result from the web service
           double conversionRate = ccs.conversionRate(Currency.GBP, Currency.USD);
           System.out.println("£1 is worth $" + conversionRate );
       }
   }
   ```

What's happening is the CurrencyConverter.java is imported as an interface, so it can't be instantiated.

It should be imported as a class. Why isn't it?

[image]

Comment: what do you want to generate? WS Server implementation or WS Client? Please also add your code when you instantiate the class.

Comment: WS client, please see example above...

Comment: how is your CurrencyConvertor looks like?

Comment: I added a screenshot... it's an interface... that's the problem it should be a class...

Comment: In the eclipse web service client wizard, what did you select as the server runtime and web service runtime?

Comment: It selects Apache Axis I can't change it... I have used http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your pb, but if you use java 1.6+ then you can generate your types with wsimport tool provided in JDK.

use following command in a terminal:

Windows:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\wsimport.exe" -keep http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL
```

Linux:

```
pathToJDK/bin/wsimport -keep http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL
```

You'll see some warnings, just ignore them. Then you'll get your class CurrencyConvertor.

I've tried this on my machine and it works!

--updated 27/07/2015---

I saw you're trying to us `wscompile`. In fact, this tool had been replaced by `wsimport` long time ago. see oracle documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxws/UsersGuide.html

Part 1.1.2 Fully Dynamic Runtime

> It should also be noted that wscompile has been replaced by two new tools: wsimport and wsgen.  wsimport is used for importing WSDLs and generating the portable artifacts.

Comment: It fixes the problem for the Currency Converter, but not for the web service I want to use, giving error: `[ERROR] undefined simple or complex type 'soapenc:Array'`

Comment: I have to use a JAX-RPC `wscompile.bat` but cannot find a copy.

Comment: Sorry for late response. wsimport generates java classes from WSDL, no matter it is a JAX-RPC or JAX-WS. I've tried with wsimport of JDK1.6.0_45 and it works. Do you continue having this error? If yes, provide more details and let's see

Answer (score 0):

Have to use wscompile from "java web services developer pack" which requires a JDK 5... and was designed for pre-win 7 OS.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-jwsdp-419428.html#jwsdp-2.0-oth-JPR

Comment: my problem is I cannot get this to install on WS7

Comment: why you insist to use wscompile? It's the old tool and has been replaced by wsimport. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxws/UsersGuide.html part 1.1.2. "It should also be noted that wscompile has been replaced by two new tools: wsimport and wsgen."

Comment: wsimport gives the error: [ERROR] undefined simple or complex type 'soapenc:Array'

Comment: you might have a pb in you wsdl, as error message indicated, maybe you are missing an XSD. without WSDL I can't give you much detail